# Vuex getter in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a `v-for` looping over dynamic data, in this `v-for` I call a Vuex getter, sometimes the result is `undefined` and I don't know why.

Here is my Vuex getter:

```
getArtistByAddress: (state) => (addr) => {
    return Object.values(state.artistsList).filter((artist) => {
        return artist.user_addr.includes(addr);
    });
}
```

Here is the isolated part of my `v-for`:

```
<div
    class="grid-item"
    v-for="(artwork, key) in artworks"
    :key="key"
    :data-index="key"
>
    <router-link
        :to="'/user/' + artwork.user_addr + '/artwork/' + artwork.txid"
        tag="div"
        class="detail"
        exact
    >
        <img
            :src="
                getArtist(artwork.user_addr)[0].user_thumb != ''
                    ? $store.state.config.ipfsGateway +
                        '/' +
                        getArtist(artwork.user_addr)[0].user_thumb
                    : emptyThumb
            "
            class="thumbnail"
        />
        <div class="title">{{ artwork.art_name }}</div>
    </router-link>
</div>
```

Here is what I get but it's quite random:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_thumb' of undefined"

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Does your `artistsList` contain an artist with `user_addr` that includes the given `artwork.user_addr`? You'll get an empty array if your getter doesn't match any artists; perhaps you should protect against that case.

Comment: Are there any AJAX calls to get the data? Could be an async issue

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the help, yes data for artistsList are async from an external API but my v-for is in a v-else that show only if $store.state.artistsList is not empty so technically it should have the data all the time and its quite random it happen like 1 out of 5 to 10 hard refresh but i noticed that i have this problem in localhost while i dev on my machine but seem to not happen when live on a server, bit weird.